# $.when with multiple promises not working as expected

Tags: jquery, azure-mobile-services

Normal call to a table in Azure Mobile service is like this:

```
var tbl1 = azureService.client.getTable('tbl1');


tbl1.where({PatientID:patientId}).read().done(
  function(result){

},
  function(err){
});
```

but when im trying with $.when I cant figure it out how should I do it.

```
$.when(tbl1.where({ PatientID: patientId }).read(),
                   tbl2.where({ PatientID: patientId }).read(),
                   tbl3.where({ PatientID: patientId }).read(),
                   tbl4.where({ PatientID: patientId }).read(),
                   tbl5.where({ PatientID: patientId }).read()).done(function (a,b,c,d,e) {
//hear a,b,c,d,e all are coming as promise() but not actual data
//how can I access data or the calling is not done right

                   }, function (err) {
                       console.log(err);
                   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object returned by the `read()` call isn't a deferred object, but a promise instead. You can convert that into a promise, and after that use the `$.when` method. The code below shows one way of doing it.

```
        var table = client.getTable("movies");
        var d1 = tableReadDeferred(table.where({ releaseYear: 2000 }));
        var d2 = tableReadDeferred(table.where({ releaseYear: 2001 }));
        $.when(d1, d2).done(function (r1, r2) {
            $("#result1").text("Result 1: " + JSON.stringify(r1));
            $("#result2").text("Result 2: " + JSON.stringify(r2));
        });
    }

    function tableReadDeferred(query) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred(function () {
            query.read().done(function (result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }, function (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
        });

        return deferred;
    }
```